# Problem with my custom LogManager

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

Here is my situation: I have a library project with the aim to overriding log4net and centralize logs with a custom appender. I have these classes :

```
myCustomLogManager
CustomLog
ICustomLog
```

In myCustomLogManager, i got this :

```
public class myCustomLogManager
{    
    public static ICustomLog GetLogger(System.Type t)
    {
        return new CustomLog(t);
    }
    // Other stuff
}
```

My custom log:

```
class CustomLog : ICustomLog
{
    private static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public CustomLog(System.Type t)
    {
        log = LogManager.GetLogger(t);
    }

    public void Debug( string message, Exception e)
    {
        log.Debug(message, e);
    }
}
```

Into my console application project, in each class, I declare :

```
private static readonly ICustomLog logger = myCustomLogManager.GetLogger(typeof(myClass));
```

When I log in myClass, no problem. But if I use another class where i log too (let's say myOtherClass), the logger name of my future log in myClass will have the value "myOtherClass". To illustrate the problem, here is an example of the output :

- [Info] myProject.myClass : "A log from myClass !"
- [Info] myProject.myOtherClass : "A log from myOtherClass !"
- [Info] myProject.myOtherClass : "A second log from myClass !!"

It's pretty hard to explain and i hope i'm clear enough, but the fact is the default logger, after doing stuff in myOtherClass class is myProject.myOtherClass and does not come back to myProject.myClass when i log in myClass class.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for reading and your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the `log` in `CustomLog` non-static:

```
private ILog log;
```

(also no need to initialize it to anything)

By having a static field you essentially just have one logger, therefore it gets changed when you use your log manager to get a "new" logger for the second class.

Comment: Hi Stefan,
Thanks a lot it's working.
It's pretty logich though, but when i were debugging, I was watching the loggers in the repository log4net and there were all my loggers. Maybe that's why i didn't thought about this static log.

Thanks again !